The RPC svc_run() function returned in a pthread
Question statement
I am developing an RPC program, using the rpcgen tool to generate the template codes. In the generated _srv.c file, the main() function does the initialization work and calls the svc_run() to wait for RPC requests to arrive. The main() code is below.
int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    register SVCXPRT *transp;

    pmap_unset (SDFS_PROG, SDFS_VERS_1);

    transp = svcudp_create(RPC_ANYSOCK);
    if (transp == NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s", "cannot create udp service.");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (!svc_register(transp, SDFS_PROG, SDFS_VERS_1, sdfs_prog_1, IPPROTO_UDP)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s", "unable to register (SDFS_PROG, SDFS_VERS_1, udp).");
        exit(1);
    }

    transp = svctcp_create(RPC_ANYSOCK, 0, 0);
    if (transp == NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s", "cannot create tcp service.");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (!svc_register(transp, SDFS_PROG, SDFS_VERS_1, sdfs_prog_1, IPPROTO_TCP)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s", "unable to register (SDFS_PROG, SDFS_VERS_1, tcp).");
        exit(1);
    }

    svc_run ();
    fprintf (stderr, "%s", "svc_run returned");
    exit (1);
    /* NOTREACHED */
}

Theoretically, the svc_run() never returns, just to wait for RPC requests.
And now, I wish to reconstruct the codes above, by putting them in a function, and creating a pthread to wait for the RPC requests. The reconstructed code is below.
static pthread_t sdfs_prog_srv_fd;
static void * 
sdfs_prog_srv_run_thread(){
    svc_run ();
    perror("sdfs rpc server thread start failed");
    return NULL;
}

void 
sdfs_prog_srv_run(){
    register SVCXPRT *transp;
    pmap_unset (SDFS_PROG, SDFS_VERS_1);

    transp = svcudp_create(RPC_ANYSOCK);
    if (transp == NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s", "cannot create udp service.");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (!svc_register(transp, SDFS_PROG, SDFS_VERS_1, sdfs_prog_1, IPPROTO_UDP)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s", "unable to register (SDFS_PROG, SDFS_VERS_1, udp).");
        exit(1);
    }

    transp = svctcp_create(RPC_ANYSOCK, 0, 0);
    if (transp == NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s", "cannot create tcp service.");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (!svc_register(transp, SDFS_PROG, SDFS_VERS_1, sdfs_prog_1, IPPROTO_TCP)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s", "unable to register (SDFS_PROG, SDFS_VERS_1, tcp).");
        exit(1);
    }
    if(pthread_create(&sdfs_prog_srv_fd, NULL, sdfs_prog_srv_run_thread, NULL)){
        fprintf (stderr, "%s", "unable to create rcp srv thread");
    }
}

However, when I run the program, the svc_run() just returned and print info sdfs rpc server thread start failed in the terminal, which is not what I want.
So I am curious about why this happened and how can I run the RPC svc in background?
Methods I have tried
I have tried some methods but with no avail.
Method 1: change the SVCXPRT *transp into a global variable
I am not familiar with the RPC mechanism and its code. I just thought the svc_run() may use some variables, and the former functions like svc_register() used the transp, but it's a local variable with a register type and will be released when the function ends. So I assumed the single svc_run() in the pthread might not be able to access the relevant variable. I claimed the transp as a global variable like:
SVCXPRT *transp;
static void * 
sdfs_prog_srv_run_thread(){
    svc_run ();
    perror("sdfs rpc server thread start failed");
    return NULL;
}

But is doesn't work.
Method 2: do not put the svc_run() in the pthread
I tried not to put the svc_run() in the pthread, like:
    if (!svc_register(transp, SDFS_PROG, SDFS_VERS_1, sdfs_prog_1, IPPROTO_TCP)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s", "unable to register (SDFS_PROG, SDFS_VERS_1, tcp).");
        exit(1);
    }
    svc_run ();
    perror("sdfs rpc server thread start failed");

The svc_run() did not return and was blocked to wait for requests, but this is not what I want.

It's probably not the source of your issue, but a pthreads thread function must accept a single parameter, of type void *, even if that parameter is unused.

What is the program's initial thread (that entered at main()) doing while the service thread runs?

What are you trying to gain by separating functions sdfs_prog_srv_run_thread() and sdfs_prog_srv_run()? Does it work as you want if you put the whole service setup and service execution in a (the same) thread?  That is, by converting all of the generated main() function into a thread function?

@John Bollinger . Thanks a lot! (1) I checked the doc online and passed void* param in the pthread function now.

@John Bollinger . (2) The main() just calls the sdfs_prog_srv_run() and sleep() functions, I am just trying to program an RPC server for further use. Generally, I need to run both an RPC server and a client in the process.

@John Bollinger . (3) Good question! At first, I just wished to extract the main codes of running a pthread, so I put the svc_run() in the pthread. Now I converted all of the generated main() in the pthread, and it did work! But I still can't figure out the reason. Maybe after I finish my programming, I would dig into this.

It is possible -- likely, even -- that the RPC back end is using thread-specific data or thread-local data (not the same thing, but they serve the same purpose).  That would ease some strategies for supporting multiple RPC services running in the same process.  But one of the costs would be that you have to run the service in the same thread in which you set it up.
